# How do I get git to ignore my csv files?

Tags: git, csv, gitignore

I want git to ignore my csv files.  But, when I do `git status`, I see that the csv is in `"Changes not staged for commit"`.  But, I swear I added it to the .gitignore file a while ago.  In fact, when I look at the `.gitignore` file, I see that it is there!

```
*.csv
```

So, how to I get `git` to ignore my csv's?  The problem is that I want to be able to do `git reset` and `git checkout` without having to worry about the `csv` files being overwritten in my working directory.

Comment: Are the csv files already checked into the git repo or is this the initial check in?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that, the csv files are already tracked in a commit before, so even though you add `*.csv` the git will start tracking the previously tracked files.

You can solve this using `git rm --cached` option, discussed in detail [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: Hmm, it answers me `fatal: pathspec 'option' did not match any files
`

Comment: check your command again. it should be `> git rm --cached` and not `> git rm --cached option` where option is considered as a file name.

Answer (score 13):

It should add `*.csv` in your .gitignore file and after that use `git rm --cached *.csv` to remove all existing csv files from your git repository